# Multiple uses of the same script causing functionality errors

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the lack of knowledge but I don't know where else to turn. I had been working on the CSS for a project while the javascript was handled by a colleague. That colleague has now left the company and I have to finish his work to hit a deadline with very little knowledge of javascript. He had created a simple function (show/hide) that allowed us to show and hide content with an unordered list. Namely when you click on a list item, the corresponding div shows and the rest hides.

This was working fine, however I have since been asked to duplicate this so that multiple (show/hides) can be used on the page. When I did this the first one works ok, but the next scripts intefere with eachother and also hide content in the other divs. I've tried to fix this using my non-existent knowledge of javascript but to know avail (attempt is below). Any help here would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```js
  function toggle(target) {

    var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('history');
    var targ = document.getElementById(target);
    var isVis = targ.style.display == 'block';

    // hide all
    for (var i = 0; i < artz.length; i++) {
      artz[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    // toggle current
    targ.style.display = isVis? 'none' : 'block';

    return false;
  } 
  
  function toggle2(target) {

    var artz2 = document.getElementsByClassName('vision');
    var targ2 = document.getElementById(target2);
    var isVis2 = targ.style.display == 'block';

    // hide all
    for (var i = 0; i < artz2.length; i++) {
      artz2[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    // toggle current
    targ2.style.display = isVis2? 'none' : 'block';

    return false;
  } 
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.slide-menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
    float: left;
}
.display-item {
    display: none;
}

.display-item:first-of-type {
    display: block;
}

.slide-menu li.current a {
    color: #75aaaf;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="slide-menu" id="first">
    <li class="current"><a href="#/" onclick="toggle('1348');">1348</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/" onclick="toggle('1558');">1558</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/" onclick="toggle('1590');">1590</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="display-item history" id="1348" style="display:block;">History Content</div>
  <div class="display-item history" id="1558">History Content2</div>
  <div class="display-item history" id="1590">History Content3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="slide-menu" id="second">
    <li class="current"><a href="#/" onclick="toggle('base');">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/" onclick="toggle('highways');">Highways</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/" onclick="toggle('transport');">Transport</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="display-item vision" id="base" style="display:block;">Vision Content</div>
  <div class="display-item vision" id="highways">Vision Content2</div>
  <div class="display-item vision" id="transport">Vision Content3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is okay if you intend duplicating the first toggle function in toggle2 function all you have to do is

Change the onclick event function from  toggle to toggle2

```
   <div class="container">
       <ul class="slide-menu" id="second">
          <li class="current"><a href="#/" 
             onclickk="toggle2('base');">Introduction</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/" 
              onclick="toggle2('highways');">Highways</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/" 
              onclick="toggle2('transport');">Transport</a></li>
       </ul>
      <div class="display-item vision" id="base" 
          style="display:block;">Vision Content</div>
      <div class="display-item vision" id="highways">Vision 
          Content2</div>
       <div class="display-item vision" id="transport">Vision 
          Content3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked a treat and makes absolute sense, thankyou. I'm annoyed with myself for not spotting where the function was called within the list items. If there's time I may try and implement the below answer from Scott Marcus as that'll be more lightweight. But for now this is exactly what I need, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't the way to set this up as it just causes the code to grow as more items need to be shown/hidden and the new code is largely the same as the old code. The original code also is more complex than it need be.

The following code will work no matter how many `container` structures you put on the page as long as you keep the structure the same as it is now. No `id`s are needed. No JQuery is needed either. You'll never need to touch the JavaScript, just add/remove HTML `containers` as you see fit.

See comments inline for details on what's happening.

```css
.container { 
  float: left; 
  border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin:10px;
  width:25%;
  padding:3px;
}

/* Don't use hyperlinks <a></a> when you aren't 
   navigating anywhere. If you just need something
   to click on, any element will do.
   
   We'll just style the clickable elements to look like links
*/
.slide-menu > li { 
  text-decoration:underline; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  color: #75aaaf;
}

.hidden { display: none; } /* This class will be toggled upon clicks */
```

```html
<!--
   Don't use hyperlinks <a></a> when you aren't 
   navigating anywhere. If you just need something
   to click on, any element will do.
   
   The elements that should be hidden by default
   will be so because of the "hidden" class that 
   they start off with.
   
   No JQuery needed for this. Keep the HTML clean and
   do all the event binding in JavaScript (no onclick="...")
-->

<div class="container">
  <ul class="slide-menu">
    <li class="current">1348</li>
    <li>1558</li>
    <li>1590</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="history" id="1348">History Content</div>
  <div class="history hidden" id="1558">History Content2</div>
  <div class="history hidden" id="1590">History Content3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="slide-menu">
    <li class="current">Introduction</li>
    <li>Highways</li>
    <li>Transport</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="vision" id="base">Vision Content</div>
  <div class="vision hidden" id="highways">Vision Content2</div>
  <div class="vision hidden" id="transport">Vision Content3</div>
</div>

<!-- The following function will run automatically when this script element
     is reached. Always keep the script just before the closing body tag (</body>). -->
<script>
  (function(){
    // Get any/all slide-menu elements into an array
    let menus =Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".slide-menu"));

    // Loop over the menus
    menus.forEach(function(menu){

      // Loop over the list items in the menu
      Array.prototype.slice.call(menu.querySelectorAll("li")).forEach(function(item, index){
        let idx = index;
        // Set up a click event handler for each item
        item.addEventListener("click", function(){
          // Get all the <div> items in this menu into an Array
          let divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(menu.parentElement.querySelectorAll("div"));
          // Hide any item that was previously showing
          divs.forEach(function(div){ div.classList.add("hidden"); });
        
          // Query the parent element (the container) for all the
          // corresponding <div> items and make it visible
          divs[idx].classList.remove("hidden");
        });
      });
    });  
   
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have no doubt you're correct and this is the way to go. However I'm not sure I'll be able to fully edit the previous code due to how the developer has embedded it into the CMS. For now I may have to go with the above answer. Thank you so much though we may use your answer at a later date.